# Perfoming formulas/calculations based off of selections on a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, drop-down-menu

```js
var stocks = [
['Apple',100,8998,723,7212],
['Microsoft',928,1992,821,2381]
];
var select = document.getElementById("selectStock");
for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
    var opt = stocks[i][0];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectStock">
    <option>Choose a stock</option>
</select>
```

I have multiple Javascript arrays of data (pulled from Excel) and have different functions that basically make calculations based on the row of the array. For example:

```
var stocks = [['Apple',100,8998,723,7212]['Microsoft,928,1992,821,2381]]
```

What I need to do is make a dropdown menu that will allow a user to select an option (Microsoft or Apple) and then based on this selection, will pull this value into the formula to make the calculations

```
document.write(Math.round(stocks[i][1] * 100)/100 + " dollars per share");
```

where i is the variable based off dropdown menu selection. Does this make sense? I'm not sure how to approach this, it's for a personal project. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can do this with a `<select>` menu that calls a function on change.  If you post your code, we can help you make it work, but I'm not sure anyone is going to write all of the code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just posted some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/b22y3v85/

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectStock");
select.onchange = (e) => {
   let index = stocks.indexOf(stocks.find(a => a.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1));
   document.write(Math.round(stocks[index][1] * 100)/100 + " dollars per share");
};
```

Comment: This works very well and is compact, so thanks! The only thing I would also need is that the values are displayed on the page and don't eliminate the drop down menu. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Instead of document.write, you could get a reference to an existing element by id and render the output there.
   
   document.getElementById('someElementId').innerText = Math.round(stocks[index][1] * 100)/100 + " dollars per share";

Comment: Thanks for the help- I really appreciate it. THe next step I need to take is having a textbox and write JS code that allows me to multiply the values by the number in that textbox. Would appreciate your help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357554/outputting-data-on-a-webpage-based-on-dropdown-menu-form-value-inputs

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, although you'll probably want to do something other than `document.write` the result.

```js
var stocks = [
  ['Apple',100,8998,723,7212],
  ['Microsoft',928,1992,821,2381]
];

var select = document.getElementById("selectStock");

for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
    var opt = stocks[i][0];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}

function getPrice(stock) {
  var price = false;
  for (var a = 0; a < stocks.length; a++) {
    if (stocks[a][0] == stock) {
      price = stocks[a][1];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!price) { alert("Incorrect choice."); return; }
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = stock + " is currently " + (Math.round(price * 100)/100 + " dollars per share");
}
```

```html
<select id="selectStock" onchange="getPrice(this.value);">
    <option>Choose a stock</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**EDIT:** Shows result in a `div` on the page, instead of overwriting the page with `document.write()`.

Comment: That works great, thanks! Is it possible to just have the result be displayed somewhere on the page instead of replacing the drop down box? I'd also need it to output multiple functions based on the output (basically the calculation for dollars per share for each of the other values in the array)

Comment: @DickThompson I changed the code to display the result on-screen instead of using `document.write()`.  To show the other values, you could just add in other divs like the results div currently there, and assign each one's `innerText` property to be the result of whichever formula you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The next step I need to take is having a textbox and write JS code that allows me to multiply the values by the number in that textbox. Would appreciate your help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357554/outputting-data-on-a-webpage-based-on-dropdown-menu-form-value-inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectStock"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var stocks = [
        ['Apple',100,8998,723,7212],
        ['Microsoft',928,1992,821,2381]
        ];
        var select = document.getElementById("selectStock");
        for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
            var opt = stocks[i][0];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.innerHTML = opt;

            el.value =stocks[i]+''; 
            select.appendChild(el);
        }
        select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
            var val = e.currentTarget.value;
            val = val.split(',');
            val.shift();
            callYourMethod(val);
        });
    </script>
```